# largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

D is a $n \times n$ diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries lies in $(0,1]$.

B is any $n \times n$ n.n.d. matrix.

What will be the sharpest upper bound on the largest eigenvalue of:

$(D+B)^{-1}D^2(D+B)^{-1}$ ?

*A naive upper bound will be $\{\min_{1\leq i \leq n}D_{ii}\}^{-1}$. Does there exist a better upper bound? As the eigenvalues of $(D+B)^{-1}D$ are real and lies in $[0,1]$, I was wondering if a better bound for $\lambda_1\{(D+B)^{-1}D^2(D+B)^{-1}\}$ can be obtained. Else, is it true that the aforementioned bound is the strongest?*

Comment: The bound is at least sharp in some cases, for instance if $D$ is the identity matrix and $B$ is the zero matrix. Besides, what kind of answer are you looking for? The best one is of course the exact value as a function of the entries in $D$ and $B$, which exists, but if $n>4$ it might be difficult to write down.

Comment: I will be happy if there is a bound which does not approach infinity as $n \to \infty$. Is it possible? $\{\min D_{ii}\}^{-1}$ may be large as $n \to \infty$ unless we restrict $D \succ \epsilon I$. Are there any other non-trivial assumptions on $D$ under which the singular values of $(D+B)^{-1}D$ are bounded as $n \to \infty$?  If not, I was wondering whether $D \succ \epsilon$ is a necessary assumption to get bounded singular values as $n \to \infty$.